# Trying to get property of non-object in my controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I used two tables to retrieve data and view it on my product page. It worked properly but when I click the "add to cart" button it says 'Trying to get property of non-object'

This is my code:

```
public function getIndex()
 {
     //display all products
     $products = DB::table('products')
         ->join('categories', 'products.category_id', '=' ,'categories.id')
         ->select('products.*', 'categories.*')
         ->paginate(6);
     //display all mobiles category
     $mobiles = DB::table('products')
         ->join('categories', 'products.category_id', '=' ,'categories.id')
         ->select('products.*', 'categories.*')
         ->where('category_id', 1)
         ->paginate(6);
     return view('shop.index', ['products' => $products, 'mobiles' => $mobiles]);

 }
//add to cart controller 
 public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id){
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->add($product, $product->id);

    $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
    return redirect()->route('product.index');
 }
```

Comment: Do you know in which line the error is occurring? Perhaps it is mentions in your error_log?

Comment: Maybe `$product` variable has has no return value.

Comment: in  line 40 this portion $cart->add($product, $product->id);

Comment: its return null @aldrin27

Comment: What is the return of `$product` variable only?

Answer (score 0):

you don't provide any error_log ,so i cannot point the problem.

i give some addvise to find the problem;

'Trying to get property of non-object' means you want to get a property from a object which is null .

First , you can look over your code and find the place where try to get a property .

Then use 'var_dump' to print the most likely place.

Finally you can find what you want

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the add to cart button when I use product table only it work properly like this

```
 public function getIndex()
 {
     $products = Product::all();
     return view('shop.index', ['products' => $products]);

 }
//add to cart controller 
 public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id){
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->add($product, $product->id);

    $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
    return redirect()->route('product.index');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so your error is actually related to your view template (specifically the Add To Cart Button) rather than the actual controller.

*Have a look at your `shop.index` and check if you're actually passing the correct `product.id` to your 'Add to Cart Button'.*

The error in your controller is due to you passing an ***invalid product id***.

This is how you'd handle the error in your controller:

```
public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id){
    $product = Product::find($id);

    /* This is how you handle your error */
    if(empty($product)) {
        // there is no valid product id being passed so return early
        return false;
    }

    $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->add($product, $product->id);

    $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
    return redirect()->route('product.index');
}
```